# Why my setitimer() is not calling SIGALRM in Linux enviroment?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I am writing below code in linux terminal but my signal is not calling any alarm after 2 second. I have set a timer using setitimer() function. what am i missing in the code ,please let me know??

```
void avg_cal_wakeup( void )
{
printf("I am signal_alarm\n");
}

int main()
{  
  
       struct itimerval tout_val;
        tout_val.it_interval.tv_sec=2;
        tout_val.it_interval.tv_usec=0;

        tout_val.it_value.tv_sec=2;
        tout_val.it_value.tv_usec=0;

        while(1)
        {
           printf("hello\n");

           if( signal(SIGALRM, avg_cal_wakeup) == SIG_ERR)
               {
                 perror(" SIGALRM didn't work \n");
                 exit(1);
              }

           //printf("bye\n");


          if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &tout_val, NULL) == -1)
             {
                perror("error calling  setitimer()\n");
                exit(1);
             }
        }
}
```

The output i m getting is only.

```
hello
hello
hello
..........
```

Comment: You *reset* the time all over in the loop. Move the whole signal and timer setup out from the loop and do it before the loop.

Comment: And you can't safely call `printf()` in a signal handler. The C standard says it's not safe - for *any* function. Per [per footnote 188 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  Some implementations expand that, and allow for the calling of **some** functions.  [POSIX allows you to call *async-signal-safe* functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03)  Note that `printf()` is not on that list.   Windows has a similar list.

Comment: Removed spurious tags.